# rst chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I am getting this error and the program stops proceeding, but it prints the output correctly !!!

This is the line I'm getting and you can notice that the error appears in the middle of the printed sentence.

> 11:45:00miA first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   n max14:00:00

```
private static FreeTime Intersection(FreeTime first, FreeTime second)
{
    Console.WriteLine("inside intersection " + first.Start + " "+ first.End + " sescond " + second.Start + " " + second.End);
    int result1 = DateTime.Compare(first.Start, second.End);
    int result2 = DateTime.Compare(first.End, second.Start);
    int result3 = DateTime.Compare(first.Start, second.Start);
    int result4 = DateTime.Compare(first.End, second.End);
    Boolean equal = (result3 == 0 && result4 == 0);

    if (!(result1 >= 0) && !(result2 <= 0) && !equal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(Math.Max(first.Start.Ticks, second.Start.Ticks)).TimeOfDay + "min max" + new DateTime(Math.Min(first.End.Ticks, second.End.Ticks)).TimeOfDay);
        return new FreeTime(new DateTime(Math.Max(first.Start.Ticks, second.Start.Ticks)), new DateTime(Math.Min(first.End.Ticks, second.End.Ticks)));
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error exactly?

Comment: The printing line           Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(Math.Max(first.Start.Ticks, second.Start.Ticks)).TimeOfDay + "min max" + new DateTime(Math.Min(first.End.Ticks, second.End.Ticks)).TimeOfDay);

Comment: It works on me. I don't see any reason not to work if both `FreeTime.Start` and `FreeTime.End` are `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes everything seems correct but this error keeps appearing!! however, Thank you for your reply